# Accessing The pathname of an anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I can see the value of the pathname of my anchor tag in firebug, but I am having a hard time accessing it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

          $("a").click(function() {
              alert("Hi");

              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "NickTracker.asmx/LogActivity",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  data: "{'path': '" + attr('pathname') + "'}",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: AjaxSucceeded,
                  error: AjaxFailed
              });

          });

      });
      function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
          alert(result.d);
      }
      function AjaxFailed(result) {
          alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
      }  
  </script>
```

Here is my html

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Page 1<br />
        <br />
&nbsp;<a href="http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-157-xml-packages.aspx">Manual</a>
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">googles</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

When a user clicks I want the path returned, this doesnt work-attr('pathname')

Comment: What do you mean by "pathname", the `href` property?

Comment: @Pekka I tried href as well still get nothing. My syntax must be wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reference the `this` object and the correct attribute, so replace `attr('pathname')` with `$(this).attr('href')` or even more simply `this.href`

`this.pathname` will only access any value after the URL hostname, which is fine if you're traversing root-relative files on your site, but will break if you're trying to access files on a different host.  For example, for `href="http://www.google.com/finance"`, `this.pathname` would result in just `/finance`

Comment: I don't understand where he got that "pathname" idea from in the first place :) it's nowhere in the code.

Comment: if you debug in firebug under the "this" node there is a property called "pathname

Comment: this works fine, but whats the properties under the "this" node wehn degugging in firebug and how do I write code to access them?

Comment: Updated answer with further explanation of `pathname`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the href attribute or even an attribute called pathname you will need to fix your attr call. What you have currently will look for a function called attr and try to pass it a string. Try: `$(this).attr("href")` or `$(this).attr('pathname')` or `this.attribute("href")`. It depends on if you are looking for an attribute you added to the anchor called pathname or the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, all it takes is just something like

```
$('a').attr('href');
```

Now if you had many different `<A>` tags in your document, that'll be a problem. You'll have to differentiate with tag you mean. Normally you do that with ids or classes.

```
$('a#myAnchor').attr('href');
```